# tomcat log4j relative path

Tags: log4j, tomcat7

Log4j works well in my application,but one strange thing happened because of my starting tomcat in different directory.Please see my following description:
The tomcat server path is `/application/servers/tomcat7.0.41`.
In my application, I define a relative log file in log4j.xml:  `../logs/test.log`

When I start the tomcat in the directory: '`/application/servers/tomcat/`' with command '`./bin/catalina.sh start`', the `test.log` file will be created '`/application/servers/logs/test.log`'.

But when I start the tomcat in the director: '`/application/servers/tomcat/bin`' with command '`./catalina.sh start`',the `test.log` file will be created '`/application/servers/tomcat7.0.41/logs/test.log`'.

Any idea to create the test.log in the path: '`/application/servers/tomcat7.0.41/logs/test.log`',no matter I start the tomcat in any directory. Something like configuring something in `catalina.sh`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use the directory pathname specified by the "`catalina.base`" system property:

```
${catalina.base}/logs/test.log
```